# Is there any integer polynomial with smooth values except constants?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, polynomials

In this problem, an integer $x$ is called smooth for some set $S$ if and only if it equals $0$ or all prime divisors of $|x|$ belong to $S$.

I suspect that for any finite set $S$, there isn't any integer non-constant polynomial $F(x)=\sum_{i=0}^n a_i x^i$ ($n>0,a_n \neq 0, a_i \in Z$) that $F(x)$ is smooth for $S$ for all $x \in Z_+$, but I'm having trouble proving it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $P(F)$ denote the set of all primes $p$ such that $p|F(x)$ for some integer value of $x$.  It is an old theorem of Schur that $P(F)$ is infinite in size, for any nonconstant polynomial $F$.  This implies the desired property.

You can see a citation and brief proof of this fact (and much more) in a lovely article in the American Mathematical Monthly, vol.78 (3) 1971, by Gerst and Brillhart, titled [On the Prime Divisors of Polynomials](http://www.jstor.org/stable/2317521).  This article is free to download, and the theorem above is titled Theorem 1, on p.253.